# Do login in Android with web service PHP

Tags: php, android, authentication

I want to make login with `JSON`. This is my login web service and my login activity  in android studio. When i attempt to login it always response 1. It means it always success. Although the username and password is wrong.

Can you tell me why is this happen?

For the database, I'm using `mysql`

login.php

```
<?php
$configs = include('config.php');

   //echo $configs['user'];

   $dbhost = $configs['host'];
   $dbuser  = $configs['user'];
   $dbpass  = $configs['pass'];
   $dbname  = $configs['dbname'];

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
     mysql_select_db($dbname);

   // array for JSON response
   $response = array();

   // check for required fields
   if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      // include db connect class
      mysql_connect($dbhost);
      mysql_select_db($dbname);
      // mysql inserting a new row
      $kueri = " SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";
      $query = '';
      $kueri.=$query;
      $result = mysql_query($kueri);

      //$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

      // check if row inserted or not
      if (!empty($result)) {
         // successfully inserted into database
         $response["sukses"] = 1;
         $response["pesan"] = "login sukses";
         // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);  
      } else {
         // failed to insert row
         $response["sukses"] = 0;
         $response["pesan"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
         // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);
      }
   } else {
      // required field is missing
      $response["sukses"] = 0;
      $response["pesan"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
      // echoing JSON response
      echo json_encode($response);
   }
?>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String URL_TEST = "http://lomapod.azurewebsites.net/login.php";
private static final String TAG_PESAN = "sukses";


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tempList;

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private Toolbar toolbar;
private EditText inputName, inputPassword;
private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutPassword;
private Button btnLogin;
private TextView txtSignUp,txtUser,txtPass;
SessionManagement session;

ProgressDialog pDialog;

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int success;
    String xuser, xpassword;

    public AttemptLogin(String xuser, String xpassword) {
        this.xuser=xuser;
        this.xpassword=xpassword;
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading . . .");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", xuser));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", xpassword));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_TEST, "POST", params);
        Log.d("Response: ", json.toString());
        try {

            success = json.getInt(TAG_PESAN);

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
                session.createLoginSession(xuser,xpassword);
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_PESAN);
            }
            else
            {
                return json.getString(TAG_PESAN);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (success == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success Login ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username & Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    session =new SessionManagement(LoginActivity.this);


    inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
    inputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    txtSignUp =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSignUp);

    inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
    inputPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputPassword));

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    ClikLogin();
    ClickSignUp();

}

public void ClikLogin()
{
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitForm();
        }
    });
}

public void ClickSignUp()
{
    txtSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}


private void submitForm() {
    if (validateName() && validatePassword()) {
        new AttemptLogin(inputName.getText().toString(),inputPassword.getText().toString()).execute();
    }

    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private boolean validateName() {
    String user=inputName.getText().toString();
    if (user==null||user.equals("")) {
        inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
        requestFocus(inputName);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}


private boolean validatePassword() {
    String pass=inputPassword.getText().toString();
    if (pass==null||pass.equals("")) {
        inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_pass));
        requestFocus(inputPassword);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}


private void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.input_name:
                validateName();
                break;
            case R.id.input_password:
                validatePassword();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think, you must test result of service http://lomapod.azurewebsites.net/login.php by web browes

Comment: @DT boss it's POST method cant test on browser, it will always return 0 on browser.

Comment: You must hashcode username and pass before test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing stop using `mysql_*` functions. Start working with `mysqli`.

Instead looking for result check for number of rows in the result like below

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rowcount>0) {
         // successfully inserted into database
         $response["sukses"] = 1;
         $response["pesan"] = "login sukses";
         // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");